# mysql search engine

Tags: php, mysql, search, database-design

I need your opinion...
I am developing an application in PHP & MYSQL (AZURE environment).
I wrote a search engine in MYSQL for the application.
The Search Engine should index pages. Each page is "split" to words and for each word a  table is created containing all of the addresses in which the word appears.

If for example the client looking for the word "tablet", the app access a table called "tablet" and will extract all the addresses in the table.
If you are searching for the two words then retrieve all addresses two relevant tables and perform cutting each address.

The problem is that at least 10 000 words i.e. 10 000 tables.
Is there a problem in DATABASE that a large number of tables?
Is the use of Microsoft's cloud server (AZURE) improves the situation?
Is the DATABASE writing to assign the tables in the cloud or just make them and the cloud takes care for this and arrange them for me?

Comment: Why are you creating a table for each word?

Comment: You have a separate table for each word? That seems like a very inefficient design.

Comment: If you have such an odd db design you should explain why you chose this.

Comment: I would look at MySQL Full Text Search - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html and lots of other models. A table per word is a ridiculous design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider solutions which do the indexing for you.
Apache Lucene is one of them http://lucene.apache.org/core/ and if you are using PHP, there are implementations in this language as well (framework.zend.com)

I would also recommend using Sphinx Search http://sphinxsearch.com. It is a great tool which will do the indexing for you. It will index the data from a DB and also provide an interface which you can query in ANSI SQL.

Comment: Thanks to all responses

My goal multiple tables is to reduce the search time.
1. No need to really look - I turn the relevant table and pulls out the 1000 results with the best score
1. I can do a search at the same time for number of words
3. Reducing the size of the table. Not require to  add  the word in each row in the table

I read about the search engines. 
At first I want to build a search engine, then I want to make the search more intuitive for example  if a user writes "I want to get rid of my car" then categorized as "sell car".

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is replicating what an inverted index pattern already does.  You should look at Lucene (java) or lucene.net (.net) for a very mature index implementation, which is open source.

As comments mention above having a table for each word (called a term in lucene) is unscaleable.